# Nothing returned from return statement

Tags: java

`nameNotNull` method is passed with name and count of names:

```
errMsgBuffer.append(Validator.nameNotNull (valueObject.getName(),count));


//Validator
public String nameNotNull(String str, int count)
{
    _logger.debug("Error message from NameNotNull :: " + str);
    String errMsg = EMPTY_STRING;
    String errorCode = null;
    if ((GenericValidator.isBlankOrNull(str)) && count>0)
    {
        errorCode = ERROR_CODE_4RV;
        _logger.debug("errorCode:: " + errorCode);
        if (errorCode != null)
        {
            errMsg = MfStringUtil.formatMsg(MfRealmProp.getMsgBundle().getString(errorCode), new Object[]{});
            _logger.debug("Error message from eNotNull :: " + errMsg);

         }
     }
     return errMsg;         
}
```

In the below logs I'm able to see the error message:

```
19 Mar 2015 23:46:09,525 DEBUG remit.util.Validator.nameNotNull - Error message from nameNotNull ::    
19 Mar 2015 23:46:09,527 DEBUG remit.util.Validator.nameNotNull - Error message from nameNotNull :: Please select a Name
```

But it is not returning to `Validator.nameNotNull(valueObject.getName(),count)`.

Did I miss anything?

Comment: First thing to do - fix your indentation. It'll be a *lot* easier to see what's going on when your code is properly indented.

Comment: Just debug the whole thing to see where it's messed up. Could be a lot of thing since you don't show every method code you use (`MfStringUtil`, `MfRealmProp`) .

Comment: What do you exactly mwan with it is not returning to your method? What is the output of your formatMsg method, maybe something is messed up there

Comment: What is the `EMPTY_STRING` for? Probably no error is occured

Comment: what is the value of `count` parameter in this case? if it is zero (0) or less, then you will receive an empty string.

Comment: Your log messages do not correspond to your code (case is different). This leads me to believe we're not look at 100% accurate info here. Either your log messages are outdated or you didn't copy/paste your code accurately.